# Kiam uzi bonan vesperon kaj bonan nokton?

Tags: word-usage

Mi jam legis, ke oni diras "bonan vesperon", kiam oni alvenas, kaj diras "bonan nokton", kiam oni adiaŭas. Sed "vespero" estas "parto de diurno, de la fino de hela tago ĝis la komenco de nokto" ([Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/vesper.html#vesper.0o.diurna)).

Kiam mi alvenas je la 23-a horo, mi devas diri "bonan vesperon"? Do kiam mi devas diri "bonan vesperon", "bonan nokton", "bonan matenon", "bonan tagon", "bonan posttagmezon" kaj alian?

Answer (score 8):

"Bonan nokton" estas adiaŭa esprimo fine de la vespero, ĉar oni deziras al la alia bonan domradon dumnoktan.

"Bonan vesperon" oni diras, kiam oni renkontiĝas kun iu en la vesperaj horoj.

Se vi adiaŭas vespere kaj volas deziri la alia bonan vesperon antaŭ la nokto, vi povas diri "Havu bonan vesperon."

Comment: Do, kiuj estas "la vesperaj horoj"?

Comment: Tion la lingvo ne precize difinas.

Answer (score 6):

Mi povas respondi pri kiel oni uzas ĉi tiujn frazojn en mia denaska nederlanda lingvo (nu, la ekvivalentajn frazojn "goeie avond" kaj "goeie nacht"), ĉar tre ofte la nederlanda lingvo funkcias simile al Esperanto. Mi ne certas, ĉu ankaŭ ĉi-kaze tio estas tiel, sed tamen eble povas esti helpema... mi esperas.

Do, en la nederlanda, oni diras "goeie avond" ("bonan vesperon") kiel saluto, kiam ankoraŭ estas vespero (do, antaŭ la noktomezo). Oni ankaŭ kutime diras "goeie nacht" ("bonan nokton") kiel adiaŭo, kiam aŭ la parolanto aŭ la parolato enlitiĝas. Tiuj du uzoj estas la plej kutimaj. Tamen, se oni renkontas nokte, kaj oni do bezonas noktan saluton, mi kredas ke oni ja povas diri "goeie nacht" tiel. Eble oni dirus "Goeie avond... of nacht al eigenlijk" ("Bonan vesperon... aŭ jam nokton, fakte"), kio montras, ke tio ne estas la plej kutima uzo de "goeie nacht"... sed tamen ja eblas, laŭ mi.

Do, ankaŭ esperantlingve, mi ja uzus "bonan nokton" se estas post noktomezo, kaj mi volas saluti iun. Verŝajne homoj, kiuj venas el alia kulturo, uzus la frazojn malsame. Tio estas unu el la malfacilaĵoj, sed ankaŭ la ĝojoj, de Esperanto :)